# Adding roles in discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

### Adding roles using discord py

I'm coding a bot on Discord, where I can mute any user just by using a simple command. Here, I tried to get the user by using the `client.fetch_user(id)` function and then add a role to the user, but I got an error saying:

> AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Here's the faulty block of code:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('$user'):
      print(message.content.split(' - '))
      muted_user = message.content.split(' - ')[1]
      muted_user = (muted_user[2:])
      role = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, name='Muted')
      print('User ID = '+ muted_user.replace(muted_user[-1], ''))
      print(client.fetch_user(muted_user[:1]))
      await client.fetch_user(muted_user[:1]).add_roles(role)
      await message.reply(muted_user[:1].name + 'has been muted!')
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Please check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052536/attributeerror-bot-object-has-no-attribute-add-roles

Comment: that isnt what i want. in the example thats given in the link you provided, theres already a member parameter. My error is beause i dont know how to mute a particular member whose id i do not know.

Comment: Why fetch user? I think you want the member object to add roles to, use `guild.get_member` or `await guild.fetch_member` (use the first one if possible)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add role in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68348615/add-role-in-discord-py)

Comment: +TheFungusAmongUS, as i mentioned, the problem im facing is that i dont know what 'member' is, since im not muting everyone who joins my server.

Comment: +Eric Jin, after reading the docs, thats what i did. however, it showed that the user i pinged didnt exist. i googled it and realised that `fetch_member` is apparently more efficient

Comment: Fetching is an api call and is *extremely* inefficient (and ratelimitey). Always use the get methods whenever possible. Also, what is the point of `muted_user = (muted_user[2:])`? Can you show an example of what the input to the command is like and the output?

Comment: +Eric Jin, `muted_user` represents the id of the user, and its in the form `<@id>`. So, i first make muted_user equal to itself without the first two chars(`<` and `@`). and then later on i use `muted_user[-1]` to remove the last char(`>`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `user = guild.get_member(discordid)`. If that person is in the server then you are able to do `await user.add_roles(role)`.

Comment: Now it says `NoneType Object has no attribute 'add_roles'`. how come its a nonetype object?

Comment: @StevensonJerod if it’s returns None that means that that user is not in that server. What code are you running?

Comment: No, I could ping the user because theyre in the server, so im positive about that. also what exactly do you mean 'What code are you running'?

Comment: @StevensonJerod I mean like what are you putting in for the guild and the discord id.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use *command* instead of *on_meessage*. And before you use *command*, make sure you have downloaded discord-ext-bot. If not, do this `pip install discord-ext-bot` in your terminal.

**In Cog:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
...

class Moderation(commands.Cog): #this SHOULD BE THE BELOW the import line
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def mute(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
        ...#put code here...
        mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted") #changed
        await member.add_roles(mute_role)
        await ctx.reply(f"{member} has been muted!"

def setup(bot): #this SHOULD BE THE END of the Cog
    bot.add_cog(Moderation(bot))
```

It should work for you.
It does not need to do get *member* because of *discord.Member*.

I am using Python 3.8.10 and it worked!

Comment: [API is here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member)

Comment: tell me if that work please. :D

Comment: So i just call the function when i say `$mute @user` and it will work?

Comment: in the args, what should ctx be? <br />
because it says `TypeError: mute() missing 1 required positional arguement: 'ctx'`

Comment: I guess you did not add the class. here is it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that [`await fetch_member()` takes an integer ID, not a string](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_member#discord.Guild.fetch_member).

In your code, you have a mention in the format `'<@12345>'`, which is then changed into `'12345'`, still a string. If you want to fetch from the api, you must convert it to an int first: `await guild.fetch_member(int(muted_user_id))`. Note that in order to add roles, you must fetch the member from the *guild*, rather than the client where you'll only get the user object.

It's probably better to use the commands extension, because then you can just do `mute(ctx, member: discord.Member)` to have it done for you.

Comment: Im positive that this is correct, however im being blocked from using the api so imma try later. thank you

Comment: when im calling the function what should be typed in place of the argument 'ctx'?

Comment: That’s if you’re using the commands extension. If you aren’t using that then you have to get the member object manually.